# jQuery CSS Hooks slow. Could be disable or fixed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, performance

I'm building a widget in JavaScript using **jQuery 1.10.2** and I used the old trick of having two divs, were the outside div is smaller and hides partially the internal div. So I use jQuery **.css()** to change left and width of the internal div allowing to implement panning and zooming of the contain of this internal div. And it's working very well, even with a complex DOM inside these internal div.

The problem is that in **Firefox** 26 and 27 is slow. I profile it, and I see that calls to "**jQuery.cssHooks[name].get()**" are being **painful slow** (in Chrome 33.0.1750.146 these calls are quick), so hurts badly the performance. It keeps being usable, but the difference and feel between Chrome and Firefox with this issue is very appreciable and unacceptable.

I find that the slow cssHooks happens when I use .css() to change the left property with pixels.

```
var left = String(- (this.view_cursor - this.options.start) * this.PPY + offset) + 'px';
var width = String(this.PPY * interval) + 'px';

this.container.css({
  left: left,   // This line launchs the painful slow cssHooks calls
  width: width,
});
```

Any idea or suggestion of how I can avoid these slow calls, or speed-up it ?
I don't find any information of somebody with a similar problem or similar issue with this.

EDIT : You can test it here : http://www.digibis.com/elgreco_digimus/es/musobjects/timeline.html?busq_concept=53

Comment: I think String(- ( should be String( -(

Comment: Do you have JSFiddeell?

Comment: I don't have JSFiddeell, but I put a link to the working prototype in a demo. I'm waiting to be allowed to put the widget in open source, and It is going to be my final degree project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so looks that is Firefox that is more slower rendering in Linux and with some drivers...
I profile it manually measuring times with JS code, and I find that Firefox takes 7 ms when Chrome takes 4 ms in the same code that redraws all...